# What is the current url format for Google Image searches?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome, url, querystring

I use a program called Cold Turkey on my laptop that blocks specific URLs, and until recently, I was able to block all google image searches as they shared part of their url. Now, however, it seems that the url format for a google image search has changed, and I haven't been able to figure out what the new format is.

I don't want to completely block Google, but I do need to block any image searches for personal reasons. Does anyone have an idea what the new url format is?